# Как подключить jQuery и Bootstrap используя ES6(Babel)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, webpack, es2016

Я хочу подключить jQuery и Twitter Bootstrap к файлу используя babel.

Я их установил `npm i bootstrap jquery --save`

у меня есть файл menu.js, которое использует их, поэтому он выглядит вот так

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';

export default {
  init:()=>{
    some code....
  }
}
```

он подключается главным файлом страницы index.js

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import menu from './menu.js';

$(document).ready(()=>{
  menu.init();
});
```

webpack выплёвывает мне index.js и common.js .В common у меня попадает jquery,bootsrap. Но при этом js мне плюётся, говорит вот что..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Басурмане решили эту проблему, но [их решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288268/using-jquery-and-bootstrap-with-es6-import-for-react-app/40558659) мне не помагает (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была такая-же проблема. Решил добавлением в `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           jQuery: "jquery",
           $: "jquery"               
       })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Да, всё правильно. Я добавлял jquery почему-то в externals)